# Android WebView loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview

I have a PHP service that returns me HTML that I display in a WebView using

```
    activity_news_complete_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Also implemented the WebViewClient as follows

```
 WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
         super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    }
};
```

In doing so when i tap on any  , the WebViewClient shows that the url attribute is about:blank but the tag contain proper urla in html variable which i load in the WebView.

Any one who can suggest me a proper solution for this would be a great help, I have read many threads on this issue but haven't found any proper solution because anything i try gives the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line replace to .loadDataWithBaseURL();

activity_news_complete_webview.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");

Its working perfectly for me. try this one.